# How to "translate" a Google Colab backend from one application's plugin/addon to another's?

Tags: python, plugins, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, stable-diffusion

I'm following a video tutorial: **Blender Stable Diffusion Plugin with Google Colab Support**.

A lot of concepts that are new to me, as although I am very familiar with Blender, I have no idea what I'm doing with Google Colab.

I've downloaded his [modified script](https://Fagiledevart.github.io/Fautomatic1111_api.py) that is mentioned between [2m36s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGX6bYZ6k38&t=156s) and 4m19s.

It's the part from [4m19s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGX6bYZ6k38&t=259s) that really confuses me, because the tutorial author references a previous tutorial that uses Google Colab in a similar way *for Gimp*. Being new to Google Colab, I do not know how to take what he did with the Gimp backend, and translate/apply that to work with Blender.

> "This is the Google Colab backend for the Gimp plugin, and we will use
> this one also for Blender. You can find [the
> link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2lCYCNQPRI&t=0s) in the
> description. Now in the previous video where I showed you how we can
> use the Gimp plugin, I also walked you through this Google Colab
> setup. So in this video I will skip the boring stuff..."

Well the "boring stuff" turns out to actually be when I don't understand, and need an explanation of.

Here is the section of the precursor video (**AI Inpaint in GIMP with Stable Diffusion on Any Platform**) from [2m21s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2lCYCNQPRI&t=141s) to 5m26s. No matter how many times I watch the video, I can't figure out which files or code snippet I'm supposed to copy from where to where.

Can some kind stranger please take a look at the relevant sections of both videos (totaling about 5min), and explain to me in simple terms what I am supposed to do? Thank you.